# Can we use chrome driver in production to take screenshots of D3charts and send in email

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am working on a project that requires to send d3 charts in email.
Like we all know JS doesnt work in email clients. so I am using chromedriver to take screenshot and embed in email and send. Do you thing this solution is feasible if the volume of users and data increases ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how your system works? Where are the d3 charts being created? where is the data coming from? is the server sending the email? do you have a server API? etc.

Comment: Data is in my database RDS (postgres). This table in database has huge amount of data. Server is ec2. Am going to add more computing power. I am having chrome driver on my server and am using pyvirtual display driver on server. I cant share more details .